# Problems with jqgrid-working with 2 grids on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have to add two jqgrids on one page. 
One will be used for displaying the records and the other one will be used for bulk insertion.
I had one grid, in order to add another one I just defined an another init grid method in the same file with different method signatures.
The problem that is occurring is when I click on Add row, two rows are added instead of one. The function is executing twice that is responsible for adding a new blank row. I am very new to jquery. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    function InitGrid1() {
    debugger

//    $grid1.find('.jqgrow td').live('click', function (e) {
//        if (e.target && e.target.nodeName != 'TD') return;
//        var $this = $(this);
//        if ($this.find('input, a').length == 0)
//            OnColumnClick($this);
//    });
    var lastSelectedRowID;
    $grid1.jqGrid({
        colNames: ['AttendancePolicyID', 'AllowedVariationID', 'New', 'Updated', 'Policy Enabled', 'Effective Date', 'Employee ID', 'Employee Name', 'Activity Type', 'After Start', 'Before End', 'Allowed Variation', 'Status', '', '', 'Payroll_f', '', ''],
        colModel: colModel,
        sortname: 'EffectiveDate',
        sortorder: "DESC",
        rowNum: 5000,
        rownumbers: true,
        rownumWidth: 30,
        autowidth: true,
        gridview: true,
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "totalpages",
            records: "totalrecords",
            cell: "cell",
            id: "ID", //index of the column with the PK in it 
            userdata: "userdata",
            repeatitems: true
        },
        prmNames: {
            rows: "numRows",
            page: "page",
            sort: "sortField",
            order: "sortOrder"
        },
        postData: {
            employeeIDs: []
        },
        datatype: function (postdata) {
            idsToDelete = new Array();
            if (reloadType == GridReloadType.PastedFromExcel || reloadType == GridReloadType.ShowingResults) {
                var griddata = {
                    totalpages: 1,
                    page: 1,
                    totalrecords: totalRowsToLoad,
                    rows: gridrows
                }; fs
                $grid1[0].addJSONData(griddata);
            }
            else if (reloadType == GridReloadType.LoadFromServer) {
                LoadAttendancePolicyFromServerpanel(postdata);
            }
            else
                LoadAttendancePolicyFromServerpanel(postdata);
        },
        gridComplete: function () {

                                  }
    });

    var $html = $('#jqgh_attendancePolicyGrid_rn').html();
    $('#jqgh_attendancePolicyGrid_rn').html('No.' + $html);
    $('.ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close').remove();

    DisableSaveButton(true);
    ResizeGrid();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        ResizeGrid();
    });

    function OnColumnClick($col) {
        try {
            var $row = $col.parent('tr:first');
            var rowid = $row.attr('id');
            if (rowid == null || $row == null)
                return;
            if ($row.find('input').length > 1)
                return;
            SaveRow(lastSelectedRowID);

        }
        catch (ex) {
            ShowMessage(ex.message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***"I had one grid, in order to add another one I just defined an another init grid method in the same file with different method signatures. The problem that is occurring is when I click on Add row, two rows are added instead of one."***
As per my knowledge, in Javascript you can create only one method with same name. (Even though signature is different,) you **cannot** create two methods with same name.

Because javascript compiler engine(browser engine) will executes with name only.

Best javascript function example in this case is: `jqGrid()`.

another way to understand is, following both functions are same:

```
function loadMsg(msg,count){
  alert(msg);
  ....
}
function loadMsg(msg){
  alert(msg);
  ....
}
```

These to methods are same.  if we call the function like `loadMsg()` also this method will execute.
Please let me know if I miss understood your question...